# xPath with optional child element (which should be returned if it exists)

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I am using the xPath functions of PHP's DOMDocument.

Let's say, I have the HTML below (to illustrate my problem):

```
<span class="price">$5.000,00</span>
<span class="newPrice">$4.000,00</span>
```

The first line is always available, but in some cases the 'newPrice-class' is in the HTML.

I used this xPath-expression, but that one always returns the 'price-class', even when the other is present. When the 'newPrice'-class is present, I only want that value. If it is not present, then I want the 'price'-class value.

```
//span[@class='price'] | //[span[@class='newPrice']
```

How can I achieve this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It perhaps helps to formulate the condition differently:

You want to select the `<span>` element with `class="price"` *only* if there is none with `class="newPrice"`. *Otherwise* you want the one with `class="newPrice"`.

```xml
//span[(not(//span[@class="newPrice"]) and @class="price") or @class="newPrice"]
```

This Xpath expression will return the element you're looking for.

*An Explanation:* The first condition can be written as the following in a predicate:

```xml
not(//span[@class="newPrice"]) and @class="price"
```

The second condition is like you had it already:

```xml
@class="newPrice"
```

With the correct parenthesis you can combine this with the `or` operator:

```xml
//span[
  (
     not(//span[@class="newPrice"]) 
     and @class="price"
  ) 
  or 
  @class="newPrice"
]
```

And as you want to obtain the price values as string, this is how it looks in a PHP example code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$expression = 'string(//span[(not(//span[@class="newPrice"]) and @class="price") or @class="newPrice"])';

echo "your price: ", $xpath->evaluate($expression), "\n";
```

Output:

```
your price: $4.000,00
```